# How do I design an exact circle tiling in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, tiles

How do I design an exact circle tiling, like the one in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03794.pdf) (first page, Figure 2, third column) but with the exact mathematical proportions?

[image]

Note that all tiles are identical.

Answer (score 6):

The central trick is that the entire figure is composed of eighteen identical 60° arcs, which are rotated by simple angles. All you have to do is create these arcs, rotate them, and put them into place (with snapping):

1. Create a circle using the *Create circles, ellipses, and arcs* tool (hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while dragging).
2. Duplicate it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>). I here make the duplicate red for better distinction.
3. Make it a 60° arc, either by dragging the handles (while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) or by manually entering the value in the *Create circles, ellipses, and arcs* tool:

   [image: Creating a 60° arc]
4. Activate *Snapping, Snap to nodes or handles* and *Snap to cusp nodes.*
5. Repeat the following twelve times:

   1. Duplicate your arc.
   2. Apply *Object → Transform → Rotate* by 30° as often as needed (or directly enter the correct value).
   3. Position the new arc as needed such that it snaps. (Start with arcs adjacent to your original one to have a basis for snapping.)

   [image: Final result]

Comment: Thank you sir! One question though: when I rotate the arch it leaves its position. How do you get them to sit exactly on the edge of the circle? (I guess I didn't understand exactly how the snapping is done)

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your problem is, but: 1) Leave the first arc in place (so other arcs can snap to it). 2) Move a second arc (e.g., with your mouse) such that one of its endpoints is very close to an endpoint of the first arc. It should then snap, such that the endpoints are in exactly the same position.

Comment: Got that now. But for some reason only the lower cusp offers to attach the duplicate, any way to make it the top cusp?

Comment: @BrunoSaramagoMonteiro: No, I cannot reproduce this problem. It may help to mirror the arc though.

Comment: That worked great, thank you for your patience :) one more question though, if I may bother: Trying to color the tiles they end up like this:

https://scontent-gru2-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/16976288_10211062772821236_1883359477_n.jpg

Any tips on how to color the whole tile and only the tile?

Comment: That link isn’t working. If you want to cover the tiles individually, you have to combine them to single objects first.

Comment: I selectd all the arches forming the tiles and united them, but then this happened when I pushed "fill":

http://i64.tinypic.com/9tpr0o.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54141/discussion-between-wrzlprmft-and-bruno-saramago-monteiro).